# Legend is cropped after exporting Print Layout to .png using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, legend, pyqgis-3

[image]
[image]

Some legends looks like that, after rendering a few layouts in a row.
I tried all these methods in the code, but in cases when previous Print Layout has smaller Legend's size - it's just doesn't work properly.

```
legend.refresh()
legend.updateLegend()
legend.adjustBoxSize()
legend.setResizeToContents(True)
```

I'm making it as a Print Layout from template.
And in a loop it sets layer's attribute and refreshs legend, and exporting a new map.

What it's can be?